# How can you print an Ada.Calendar.Time variable in Ada?

Tags: ada

Need to know how to print a Time variable in Ada. I assume there is no portable way because Time is implementation defined. I've already seen the GNAT.Calendar.Formatting package available under GNAT, I'd also be interested in a GHS for VME.

Answer (score 3):

See package "Ada.Calendar.Formatting" function "Image" for Ada2005. If you have an Ada95 compiler you could and this package isn't available, try my implementation from [here](http://www.martin.dowie.btinternet.co.uk/Calendar/Calendar.zip)

This was written using GNAT 3.15p, so pretty old.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, time output can be portable, Ada.Calendar contains standard functions that extract the components of a time value, so it's straightforward to put together your own conversion package.

For example, here's [one](http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=AdaLibs&CID=190). One just needs to either create a minor addition to create a "Formatted_Time" record for a given Time value (see the package's Get_Time() function for guidance), or make Main_Formatter() visible in the package spec.

Answer (score 1):

Generally what I do is use Calendar.Split and then do a 'image on the parts I care about.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that displays the date and time using the GNAT.Calendar.Time_IO package:

```
with ada.calendar;
with gnat.calendar.time_io;

procedure display_time is
begin
  gnat.calendar.time_io.put_time(ada.calendar.clock, "Date: %Y/%m/%d Time: %H:%M:%S");
end display_time;
```

Date/time format options are available here:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Libraries/GNAT.Calendar.Time_IO